# How can I horizontally center a single line of text in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview, text-alignment

I have a UITextView which displays a fair amount of text. I need to horizontally center some, but not all, of the lines of text in the text view.

I've tried setting the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` with an NSParagraphStyle instance whose `alignment` property is `NSTextAlignmentCenter` on the range of the line to be centered. I'm also setting the font so the centered line is bold. When I do this using the code below, the relevant line is bolded, but remains left aligned.

```
if (shouldCenterLine) {
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *centerStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    centerStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : centerStyle,
                                 NSFontAttributeName : boldFont};
    [attributedString setAttributes:attributes range:lineRange];
}
```

If I apply this same paragraph style attribute to the entire contents of the text view, the text ends up centered as expected.

Is it possible to convince `UITextView` to center specific subranges of its text? Is the only solution to move to a `UIWebView` rendering generated HTML? Note that this is for an app still supporting iOS 6, so unfortunately I'm not able to use Text Kit.

Comment: I have no experience with trying to change the paragraph style, but I think I'd try a wider range. What range are you using right now? Does it include the line return that ends the line? Does it include the line return that starts the line? Maybe just try including a few characters before and after. If it still doesn't work, try doing the whole string, just to verify that it recognizes `NSTextAlignmentCenter`. (Including the code that produces `lineRange` would probably be helpful.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Thanks! Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Expanding `lineRange` to include the newline before the line to be centered (ie. adding one additional character to the beginning) fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear I helped. It's the first time I've ever looked at StackOverflow's front page and saw something that I could both help with and nobody else had answered yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the line returns around the the line that you'd like centered within the range that you apply the style to.