# Swift iOS TextView center and right align certain text

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have a textview and I want it similar to the iphone notes app. When a user clicks on the center align button I only want whatever is on that line to be center aligned. I have this code but when I use it, it sets the entire textview text to be center aligned, I only want the line I am on to be center aligned:

```
@IBAction func centerAlignmentBtn(_ sender: Any) {
     self.textView.textAlignment = .center
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128306/how-can-i-horizontally-center-a-single-line-of-text-in-uitextview

Answer (score 1):

you can set alignment justified and then set text writing direction.
like as it.

```
self.textView.textAlignment = .justified //set text alignment center and justified
self.textView.makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft(true)//if you want set writing direction right to left
self.textView.makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight(true)//if you want set writing direction left to right
```